# How to find DNS servers for each PPP session in linux?

Tags: linux, ppp, pppd

How to get the DNS server address which are specific to each ppp session. For example, I have to ppp sessions each one connected different service provider, how do I find out the DNS server IP address which are assigned by each service provider? In general, the /etc/ppp/resolv.conf file will be overwritten with the new DNS IP address whenever a new ppp session is established. Is there any way how we can maintain separate files for DNS servers for each service provider?

Comment: Looks to be a question for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ppp comes with scripts to update resolv.conf for you. Look at /etc/ppp/ip-up and /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/0dns-up. The last one has the rules for updating the resolv.conf file. ($DNS1 and $DNS2 variables).

You can add an ip-up.d script if you want.